# Add DNAME record to dnsmasq config file using dns-rr

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) on my home router to manage some local only DNS records and create [split-horizon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) responses for a personal public domain name. I also recently added synth-domain settings to generate ip-192-168-0-1.net.home.arpa and vm-1.vm.home.arpa style records using the new [home.arpa](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375) DNS zone (see [details](https://twitter.com/GBrayUT/status/1030261029064695811) if interested).

I would like to try using a [DNAME record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6672) to delegate the internal.home.arpa zone to be an alias of the existing split-horizon public domain zone (meaning each lookup would basically be a CNAME to the same record on my public domain), but dnsmasq does not have explicit support for DNAME records.

My question is: how can I use the [dns-rr setting](https://serverfault.com/q/914108/33095) to create the DNAME record? I know the record type is 39, but I'm not sure how to generate the raw hex data.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the python script found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/925550/33095) I am able to generate the raw hex data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import dns.rdata
import io
import binascii

name = "example.home.arpa"
rclass = dns.rdataclass.IN
rtype = dns.rdatatype.DNAME
rdata = 'example.com.'


rd = dns.rdata.from_text(rclass, rtype, rdata)
f = io.BytesIO()
rd.to_wire(f)
wire_data = f.getvalue()
print("dnsmasq option: --dns-rr=" + name + "," + str(rtype) + "," + binascii.hexlify(wire_data).decode("ascii"))
```

Which results in the following /etc/dnsmasq.d/home.conf settings:

```
local=/home.arpa/
dns-rr=example.home.arpa,39,076578616d706c6503636f6d00
```

However I it doesn't work as expected. I can see the DNAME response, but dnsmasq doesn't respond to other queries for that zone with the expected alias records:

```
$ nslookup -type=any example.home.arpa
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

example.home.arpa   dname = example.com.


$ nslookup -type=a www.example.home.arpa
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find www.example.home.arpa: NXDOMAIN


$ nslookup -type=a www.example.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

Which leads me to believe that dnsmasq currently doesn't support hosting zones using DNAME. Maybe next I'll try forwarding those requests to another DNS server like coredns or bind using `server=/example.home.arpa/192.168.0.53/` and see if that works.

**UPDATE:** using [coredns to host the DNAME record](https://gist.github.com/gbrayut/3007c66ef9f6e02c7ab99cb875c106d2) and then forward the zone from dnsmasq using server= seems to work. But best I can tell dnsmasq does not natively support DNAME records.

Comment: DNAME means special processing from the DNS server, it is not just a record. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6672#section-3  So a tool that is not programmed with the special logic for DNAME will not handle DNAME as specified by the RFC and will just deliver the record like any other one, which is useless.